# Mobile app for cryptocurrency trading with multiple exchanges via API

Tags: android, ios, mobile, finance

I am looking for a mobile app (Android and/or iOS) which would allow me to compare, trade currencies with multiple providers, and tracking my portfolio.

For example, I am aware of *Binance* mobile app, but it doesn't support any other major exchanges at one place.

Ideally free, but can be paid as well.

Comment: I've not yet used any, but my [Android app listing on Crypto-Currencies](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/finance_crypto) should offer you some candidates. Especially check the sections on Trading and Exchanges (and the Multi-Currency Wallets; some of them have trading capabilities built-in).

Answer (score 0):

- [Tab Trader](https://tab-trader.com/) (Android and iOS)

  > Manage all your exchange accounts through a unified interface. Make charts, add trend, horizontal lines and technical indicators with ease. The forecast will help you finetune your strategy, maximise returns and minimise losses.

  It is free for now, but it's going to be premium soon.
- [Coinigy](https://www.coinigy.com/apps/) (Android & iOS)

  > Coinigy is the most comprehensive bitcoin and cryptocurrency trading and portfolio management tool available. With extensive charting tools and real-time market data, no other cryptocurrency app can match Coinigy in its scope, detail, and performance.

<sup>Source: [Is there a Bittrex Android app?](https://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoCurrency/comments/6errui/is_there_a_bittrex_android_app/)</sup>